# WooCommerce products: Wrong product permalink in custom loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, woocommerce, permalinks

I'm using a custom loop to show a selection of products.
The loop works fine and shows the products with the correct title, image and the other stuff.
But the permalink is the URL of the current page.

If I add `$post` inside the permalink, everything works fine: `get_permalink($post)`

Here's my current code:

```
<?php $featured_posts = $products_select; if( $products_select ): ?>
<div>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach( $featured_posts as $post ): setup_postdata($post); ?>
            <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div>
```

I checked the content of `$products_select` and saw, that there is no link stored.
Could that be the problem? Is there any way to correct the permalink?

The variable `$products_select` is the output of a custom field based on [relationship field from Advanced Custom Fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/relationship/). It is stored as post object.

Comment: Have you tried `var_dum()` your variables to see that they contain an ID or similar that you can use to fetch the permalink? The main thing you need is the ID of the post. If your variables are objects, then you can do `$post->ID` or `$product->ID`. Alternatively, if you have the slug available: `get_permalink( get_page_by_path( 'slug_name' ) );`.

Comment: Yes, the ID is there and it works when I add `$post` to the function (see above). But I want/need to use `wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );`. So there isn't an option to change the code for the permalink. And the code looks like this: `echo '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link">';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

Don't use `get_posts()` function, instead use a real `WP_Query` like in the following example:

```
<?php
$loop = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
) ); 
?>
<div>
    <ul><?php
if ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    echo '<pre>ID: '.get_the_id().' | Title: '. get_the_title() . ' | Link: ' . get_permalink() . '</pre>';
    wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
endif;?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This time it will works, without any issue.

---

**An alternative:** To avoid this problem, you could use instead WooCommerce `[products]` shortcode as follows:

```
<?php 
$featured_posts = $products_select; if( $products_select ): 

// get a comma separated string of product Ids
$post_ids = implode( ',', wp_list_pluck( $featured_posts, 'ID' ) ); 

// Use [products] shortcode with the comma separated string of product Ids
echo do_shortcode("[products ids='$post_ids']" ); ?>
</div>
```

Tested and works.

Comment: @Cray In my case only the first one is with a wrong permalink… You could alternatively use "products" shortcode like in my updated answer code.

Comment: That works, thank you! But in this case I'm not in control of the sorting anymore (reason for the custom loop and the use of the relationship field). I didn't mention that in my question. So the question is solved. But I still don't understand the roots of the problem :-(

Comment: @Cray This is just a temporary alternative, I will try to find out how to get that working, later on.

Comment: I realized that the title is missing too. I must have overlooked that in my first attempt. Maybe it's "just" a bug of WooCommerce?

Comment: That's it. Thank you so much ;)

Answer (score 0):

I also found a soultion that will work with Advanced Custom Fields and keeps the custom order of the relationship field:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post__in' => $products_select,
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'orderby' =>  'post__in' 
    );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $loop->have_posts() ) : ?>
<div>
    <ul>
        <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
            <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
</div>  
<?php endif;  wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```